# How do I enter text without a control ID using AutoIt?

Tags: autoit

I have a window containing a text box. How do I enter text by clicking the mouse and entering the text in a text box?

Answer (score 2):

You can normally 'cycle' through the input boxes with `Send("{Tab}")` or `Send("{Tab 5}")` for 5 times the press of a Tabulator-Key. And then you can use the normal `Send("input text")` stuff to insert whatever you want. You can also use the `ClipPut("content")` to fill the Clipboard with some stuff and then only use the `Send("^v")` ("^" equals "{Ctrl}", the see [Send Key List](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm)) to insert whatever you placed there - and optionally save the clipboard content before with `ClipGet()` and then restore it afterwards. Before it's typically `WinActivate("Window Title")` to set the window active you want to send your key strokes to. Good luck!

And last, but not least... if your input elements' position is fixed, you can just click into it before to activate them, see `Opt("MouseCoordMode", 0)` for window-relative coordinate positioning and then use something like [`MouseClick("primary", 20, 65, 1, 0)`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Control ID isn't the only way you can address a control. You can use the control class and instance as well. For example

```
ControlSetText("Untitled - Notepad", "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", "hello world!")
```

You can get the class/instance details using the AutoIt Window Info tool that comes with AutoIt.

That is much safer than Send. But sometimes using Send is unavoidable. You could also use SendKeepActive which tries to keep a certain window active as you send keystrokes to it.